# User-defined literal operator isn't recognised in my class

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

I have written a class that uses literal operators to indicate a measurement error to be used in physical applications. I have defined a literal `""_err` that takes `long double` as an argument and returns a struct called `Error`. For instance, `1.3_err`.

A `friend` declaration for this literal is placed in the header file `TStat.h`, and the definition is placed in `TStat.cpp`, as you'll see in the code below.

However, I got an error when compiling with an example like `b = 0.4_err` where `b` is `Error`. In the error it says it couldn't find the literal operator. You may check the error message at the end of this question.

I have tried many combinations, like defining the literal internally or externally, etc. I have searched similar questions but everything seems fine in the code, just like it is described by many tutorials and other C++ sources.

As a particle physicist, I use a C/C++ library called [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch) developed by CERN which is actually a C/C++ interpreter. There, I could use this class without any errors (I haven't used any ROOT class at all). However, when I compile my code by `g++` with `c++11` flag, no match for the literal could be found.

This is the header file:

```
#ifdef TSTAT_H
#define TSTAT_H

namespace TStat {
    struct Error {
        // ...
    }

    class Double {
        // constructors, etc.
        // ...

        friend Error operator "" _err (long double);
    }
}
```

and this is the TStat.cpp file:

```cpp
#include "TStat.h"

using namespace TStat;

// ...

TStat::Error operator"" _err(long double err) {
    TStat::Error error;
    // ...
    return error;
}
```

When compiled with the following command in the terminal (I am using MacOS)

```
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 example.cpp TStat.cpp -o example.exe
```

I get an error saying

```
example.cpp:6:12: error: no matching literal operator for call to
  'operator""_err' with argument of type 'long double' or
  'const char *', and no matching literal operator template
b = 0.4_err;
```

for an example.cpp like this:

```
#include "TStat.h"

using namespace TStat;

int main() {
    Error b;
    b = 0.4_err;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no line `b = 0.4_err;` in the posted code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I added the example.cpp code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `friend` declaration does not bring the declared name in any other scope. In this case, it doesn't even bring the name in the scope of the class itself:

> [class.friend]/7 A friend function defined in a class is in the (lexical) scope of the class in which it is defined. A friend function defined outside the class is not (6.4.1).

but that's irrelevant for the case shown. `main` won't see any `friend` declaration in any class.

The easiest fix is to declare `operator "" _err` in `TStat.h` at the top level outside of any class.

Comment: Oh, it worked! However, this generates another error when I try to define `TStat::Double operator+ (double, TStat::Error)` which was working before. Is it related or should I start a new question?

Comment: @OktayDoğangün I think a new one will be better

Comment: P.S.: I have solved that one (it was because of a silly mistake).